# Is there a way to read a file from a Kerberized HDFS into a non kerberized spark cluster given the keytab file, principal and other details?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, webhdfs

I need to read data from a Kerberized HDFS cluster using [`webHDFS`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) in a non Kerberized Spark cluster. I have access to the Keytab file, username/principal, and can access any other details needed to log in. I need to programmatically log in and allow my Spark cluster to read the file(s) from the Kerberized HDFS.

It looks like I can log in using this piece of code:

```scala
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "<kdc>")
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "<realm>")
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf)
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("<my-principal>", "<keytab-file-path>/keytabFile.keytab")
```

From the official documentation of `webHDFS` [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#HDFS_Configuration_Options), I see that I can configure the keytab file path and principal in the hadoop configuration like this:

```scala
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.principal", "<my-principal>")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.keytab", "<keytab-file-path>/keytabFile.keytab")
```

After this, I should be able to read the files from the Kerberized HDFS cluster using:

```scala
val irisDFWebHDFS = sparkSession.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(s"webhdfs://<namenode-host>:<namenode-port>/user/hadoop/iris.csv")
```

But it still refuses to read and throws the following exception:

```scala
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Authentication required
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.validateResponse(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:490)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.access$300(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:135)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.connect(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:721)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:796)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:619)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:657)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:653)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getDelegationToken(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1741)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getDelegationToken(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:365)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getAuthParameters(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:585)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.toUrl(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:608)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractFsPathRunner.getUrl(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:898)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:794)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:619)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:657)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:653)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getHdfsFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1086)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1097)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1707)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:376)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:796)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:596)
  ... 44 elided
```

Any pointers on what I might be missing?

Comment: Don't mix the documentation for the Hadoop **services** (e.g. HDFS REST API a.k.a. webHDFS) and the documentation for the Spark **client**. There are multiple ways to pass Kerberos creds to Spark, but the Hadoop service you want to reach makes no difference.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense, can you help me with how I can do this and pass the Kerberos creds to Spark?
I was under the (perhaps wrong?) assumption that I can configure `webHDFS` with my spark client since that is the File System I wanted to read from.
If that's not the right way, what would be the right way to approach this problem then?

Comment: Option 1: search the Spark documentation for `kerberos` keyword. Option 2 : google `spark kerberos principal keytab`, open a few links, go back to option 1 for extra details. Option 3: wait for someone patient enough to explain it to you on StackOverflow. I advise options 1 and 2.